# Unable to get the value from the input field using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, i have created an input field for date, i want to get the value of the date input field but i couldn't get the value. Can anyone help me in this?

sample code:

```
<Form.Input
  label="Date of Birth"
  name="date"
  type="date"
  placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
  value={this.props.date}
  onChange={this.props.changeDate}
/>;
```

Can Anyone help me in this?

Comment: where are you trying to read the date value? it lives in the parent component

Comment: On change it is correctly setting the date property in your state.
They are also correctly passed into your Display component.
What is the required behaviour?

Comment: @TomSlutsky - Sorry, I've updated my code link. I want get the date value, for example if i give 01-01-2001 then when submitting the value i want to get the respective value. moreover there is an issue with year (yyyy) - it should take only 4 digits.

Comment: @UtsavPatel - Hi, I want get the date value, for example if i give 01-01-2001 then when submitting the value i want to get the respective value. moreover there is an issue with year (yyyy) - it should take only 4 digits

Comment: Not sure what you mean.
On change it correctly sets the value and I can see the value in props of display component too.
Do you mean you want the format of date as DD-MM-YYYY whereas you get YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @UtsavPatel - You're correct it is showing in  this `YYYY-MM-DD` format but i want it in this format`DD-MM-YYYY`, and one more issue is yyyy is taking more than 4 digits. Is it possible to make the `yyyy ` to have only 4 digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert YYYY-MM-DD back to DD-MM-YYYY format

You can use regex

```
'2021-01-01'.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/,'$3-$2-$1')
```

gives "01-01-2021"

In your case:

```
   handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let dateval=this.state.date.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/,'$3-$2-$1')
    const data = {
      date: dateval
    };
    console.log(data);
  };
```

Comment: When i add regex to my onChange method, if i write date and month it is showing but when i write year the date and month is getting disappear.

Comment: U can use in changeDate function in App.js file.I have updated my answer.

Comment: it's not accepting date properly, if i type month then date is getting disappear even for year also i'm facing the same issue

Comment: This is because 2020-01-01  is the format your form input is expecting

Comment: could you please assist me to make it correct way? Do i need to change the input field?

Comment: I assume you require correct format while submitting form. In that case u can convert date to correct format in handleSubmit function. I have updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

It is setting the date value in the state (date) as expected but where you are trying access it other than submit button and in your codesandbox the submit button is not visible.